# Django return to trigger the error view in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have the following view in django:

```
def update_card(request):
    return HttpResponse(status=400, message="You cannot call this method").
```

And in jquery:

```
$.ajax({

    url: "{% url 'update_card' %}",
    type: 'POST',


    success: function(data){
        console.log('OK!')
    },

    error: function(err){
        var response_message = err.responseText;
        alert(err.responseText)
    }

 });
```

But for whatever reason, this is triggering the `success` method unless I do something like `raise Exception(200, "You cannot call this method")`. Why? Am I not allowed to return a HttpResponse object to jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many types of responses that you can send. Also, you don't need to send status codes.

1. HttpResponseBadRequest('error message') // status code 400
2. HttpResponseServerError("error message") // status code 500
3. raise SuspiciousOperation('error message') // exception
4. raise Exception('error message') // Status code 500

Your javascript code will remain the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have it in the reverse order. It needs to be:

```
return HttpResponse("You cannot call this method", status=400)
```